pgrouting or recursive question?
For a water network, I'd like to count the users and accumulate them. I look at
Here's what I've got:

and I'd like to get (done by hand):


however, with a recursive query, I'm afraid of counting errors (see image 2).
What do you think is the best approach? pgRouting (how?), recursive query, python... I'm using postgis and QGis, can Network or other plugin help me?
Basically, what would be the best method?
I read Algorithm for recursive network optimization but I'm lost :(

I would think your 76 in the MUST HAVE image should be 85, and the answer to your question is SELECT SUM(<users>) FROM <that_network>, potentially using something like ... WHERE <target_vertex_id> < 13;

No, in the must have image, real number is 76 : 61+15. In image 2, I have 2 results : 71 62+9, 61+9 but It's not reality. And my network is more complex, with many vertex.thk for your help

5+2+0+1+6+3+14+4+12+8+6+5+10+9 = 85 <~> SUM(users) - if edge [6|9] => 17+18+12 then edge [12|13] => 61+15+9, not sure why you'd drop the 9 here.

Ok, my fault, sorry, I drop 9, result should 15+61+9= 85, but I need result for all vertices not just for last.

You can use networkx with the ancestors method:

Returns all nodes having a path to source in G.


import networkx as nx

#Create a directed Graph
G = nx.DiGraph()
edges = [(1,2,5), (2,5,0), (3,2,2), (3,4,1), (4,5,6), 
         (5,6,3), (7,8,14), (8,6,4), (6,9,12), 
         (9,11,8), (10,9,5),(10,12,10), (11,12,6),
         (12,13,9)] #A list of edges as tuple (node1, node2, weight), ...]

for edge in edges:
    n1, n2, weight = edge 
    G.add_edge(n1, n2, volume=weight)

#Find the cumulative weight 
target = 13 #Target node
print(G.subgraph(nx.ancestors(G, target)|{target}).size(weight='volume'))
#85.0

(It is possible to create the graph programmatically)
